# Scoring rules for time series data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, predictive-models, asymptotics, scoring-rules

I have found quite a lot of articles about scoring rules that seem to first work out theorems and proofs for scoring rules in an iid setting, after which they proceed to apply them to some time series data (such as financial returns). However, I'm unable to find a paper that somewhat rigorously describes how to translate concepts such as (strict) propriety from an iid (or single observation) setting to a time series forecasting context. Do you happen to know any sources on the technical details and use of scoring rules for time series?

For example, what is the usual way to define propriety for a scoring rule in a time series context? Suppose $S$ is some scoring rule. I was thinking about something like defining an 'asymptotic' expectation first. If $A$ is some predictive model, define $S(A, Y_T) = \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T S(A_{t|t-1}, y_t)$. For some 'true model' $D$ we then assume $\lim_{T\to\infty} S(A, Y_T) = S(A, D)$ for some constant $S(A, D),$ $D-$a.s. I would then call $S$ proper (or 'asymptotically' proper perhaps?) if $S(A, D)\geq S(D, D)$ for all $A, D$. Is this a sensible definition for propriety of a scoring rule in a time series context, or is a different definition generally used?

I also find it hard to generalize this notion of propriety to strict propriety, since models might differ only for some finite number of observations and be the same after that, which would still result in the same score, while being different. So similarly, does someone here happen to know how strict propriety of scoring rules is usually defined for time series?

Comment: Maybe the initial discussion here is useful? https://www.ecb.europa.eu//pub/pdf/scpwps/ecbwp1017.pdf

Comment: @hejseb: thanks for the suggestion. I indeed read that paper and that is where I originally got the question (and my proposed definition) from. However, they do not really discuss what localness and propriety mean in a time series context, but instead refer to some sources that treat scoring rules in a single observation or iid setting.

Answer (score 1):

From what I have seen, people will work with the "iid definitions" of (strict) propriety and pretty much work "pointwise", even in time series forecasting contexts.

For examples, see papers of Gneiting and colleagues, who routinely illustrates his papers with meteorological forecasts. I am certainly no expert in meteorological forecasting, but judging from what I have seen, this approach is common there, all the way back to [Brier's (1950) original paper](https://doi.org/10.1175/1520-0493(1950)078%3C0001:VOFEIT%3E2.0.CO;2).

For a recent example, take a look at [Ehm et al. (2016, with discussion)](https://doi.org/10.1111/rssb.12154). Ehm et al. and discussants also refer to [Strähl & Ziegel (2015)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.05314.pdf), who specifically look at calibration in a time series context, and even they (section 5.3) use this "pointwise" approach.

Bottom line: the "pointwise" approach seems to be the state of the art for scoring rules in time series. Of course, that does not mean it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a reason why we would need some extra definition for the time series situation. The definitions of scoring rules and (strict) propriety do not require any assumption on the dependence between different observations, in particular no i.i.d. assumption. Hence, they are perfectly valid, and also commonly applied, in forecast evaluations based on time series data.

To be precise, a scoring rule assigns a score $S(G, y)$ to any pair of probability distribution $G$ and observation $y \in \mathbb{R}^d$. The distribution $G$ could be anything from the success probability $p \in [0, 1]$ of a binary outcome to a density function on the real numbers. $S$ is proper if
$$
\mathbb{E}_{Y \sim F} S(F, Y) \le \mathbb{E}_{Y \sim F} S(G, Y)
$$
for all $F, G \in \mathcal{G}$, where $\mathcal{G}$ is some class of distributions. It is strictly proper if equality of the expectations implies $F=G$. In other words, the true distribution of the observation minimizes the expected score. There is no dependency assumption involved and we could also rewrite this definition such that no random variable appears, at all.

In a time series setting, a forecaster would have some information at time $t-1$ specified by some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_{t-1}$ and would produce some forecast $G_t$ of the distribution of $Y_t \vert \mathcal{F}_{t-1}$. To judge whether one forecaster achieves lower expected scores than a competitor, we would estimate the score difference of their predictions $(G_t)$ and $(H_t)$ via
$$
\frac{1}{n} \sum_{t=1}^{n} \left( S(G_t, y_t) - S(H_t, y_t) \right) .
$$
If the $Y_1, \ldots, Y_n$ are i.i.d. this estimates the expected scores w.r.t. a single $Y$, i.e. $\mathbb{E} (S(G, Y) - S(H, Y) )$. For a general time series we need to add assumptions like stationarity or ergodicity to ensure that we estimate something meaningful. Although we then estimate some mixture of expected scores (since the distribution of the $Y_t$ varies), propriety still ensures that high positive or negative values indicate differences in predictive performance.

For the definition and more background on proper scoring rules see [Gneiting and Raftery (2007). Strictly Proper Scoring Rules, Prediction, and Estimation.](https://doi.org/10.1198/016214506000001437)